# Short Names only works on C Drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find the short name of a path on Windows.

For some reason the following command only works when run on the C drive

```
for /d %I in (*) do @echo %~sI
```

I would like the short name of a folder on my D drive.

Comment: Check this. Especially the registry configurations.  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5291

Comment: If the D drive is a CD/DVD drive, the disk might not have been written to include short filenames, and even if it was I'm not sure whether Windows actually supports reading them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your 8.3 notation is turnred on for the other drives:
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx