# GetShortPathName fails with Chinese folder on a network drive

Tags: c++, c, winapi, window

I want to get a short path name with the function GetShortPathName on a network drive, F:\, with a Chinese folder name. When I run the EXE file from that folder I don't see it is able to obtain the short path name. When I do that from the C:\ drive everything works fine.

Here is my code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 4096


bool GetIsCaseCorrect(const WCHAR* fileName)
{
    bool result = false;
    // Correct case by converting to short path and back to long
    WCHAR shortFileName[_MAX_PATH];
    if (GetShortPathName(fileName, shortFileName, _MAX_PATH) != 0)
    {
        wchar_t correctFileName[_MAX_PATH];
        wcout << "ShortFile " << shortFileName;
        GetLongPathName(shortFileName, correctFileName, _MAX_PATH);
        result = wcscmp(fileName, correctFileName) != 0;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    bool ret;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(hModule, path, MAX_PATH);

    ret = GetIsCaseCorrect(path);
    getchar();
}
```

If I run this program the short path is not displayed on a non-system drive where folder is in Chinese.

My Windows OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Are you compiling with wide strings?

Comment: Please post the complete program and some hint of how you are compiling it.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, That is my complete program. I Use Unicode Character Set is in Visual Studio. On Drive C \你好\a.exe C:\你好\test.txtit works fine.

Comment: What's the error returned from `GetShortPathName` (or any other function that fails)?

Comment: @chris, no error. the output of the program looks like this. The full path name is:  F:\???\Test.txt
The short name for F:\???\Test.txt is F:\???\Test.txt
The long name for F:\???\Test.txt is F:\???\Test.txt

Comment: On the other hand , on drive c:\ the Output looks like this: C:\???? ??>GetShortPathName.exe "C:\???? ??\Test.txt"
The full path name is:  C:\???? ??\Test.txt
The short name for C:\???? ??\Test.txt is C:\86A9~1\Test.txt
The long name for C:\86A9~1\Test.txt is C:\???? ??\Test.txt

Comment: I fail to see how that can be the complete program. Are you able to compile it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Yes of course i am able to compile it.It is a very short program. I just omitted #includes and using namespace std for readability.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068756/short-names-only-works-on-c-drive) is related?

Comment: @chris, thanks. I will try that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, what do you link it with? it does not link for me as is. Why omit anything making people help you? Please specify compiler and provide main() etc. A small complete program would help.

Comment: [mcve] would help. Don't understand why you use TCHAR rather than wchar_t.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, as i said the local drive works fine. So probably it is not connected to wchar_t. Perhaps , you have a working example , or show me the right direction.

Comment: That's not how it works here. [mcve] please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i edited the full code example.

Comment: So I guess the issue is the way that the network volume is configured. Not all filesystems will have full support for short names. You certainly should not be using short names at all. You will solve your problem by simply avoiding ever using short names.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Windows 7 machine takes with the SMB 2.0 by default. GetShortPathNameW method is better supported with SMB 3.0.

You could follow this document below to enable SMB 3.0 with Win7.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0

Or you could follow this document below to check the volume state for Disable8dot3.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2013/10/09/getshortpathname-doesnt-return-short-path-name/

Best Regards,

Baron Bi